# How to configure VM to mount filesystem share as writable

Tags: mount, filesystem, qemu

Here is my situation.  I have a host computer running ubuntu server 14.04
It mounts a dev from fstab:

```
  /dev/sdb2 /media ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Permissions on the mounted folder are owner=root, group=root, view content, change content, and accesss content are all =anyone.

Everything on the host machine works fine.

The host has a virtual ubuntu server 14.04 created with virt-manager.  In virtmanager I create a writable filesystem mode=passthrough, driver=default, source=/media, target=hostmedia

On this VM I mount the fiesystem in fstab with:

```
  hostmedia /media 9p trans-virtio,_netdev, rw, acl 0 0
```

On this guest VM, only root can create/modify/delete files.  Every other user has read only.  I can't figure out how to change this.